# Gravity-Spin coupling in SME

Tags: gravity, quantum-spin, beyond-the-standard-model

I'm trying to understand why there are theoretical models predicting that spin and gravity should couple.

Specifically, what I'm asking is if such Standard Model extension comes from gauging the Poincaré group as per the Cartan variant of GR, where  additionally torsion is sourced by spin instead of just energy and momentum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gauge field of local supersymmetry (=supergravity) - gravitino - leads to non-trivial torsion. [Gravitino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitino) is a spin-$\frac{3}{2}$ field satisfying [Rarita-Schwinger equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rarita%E2%80%93Schwinger_equation).

**Update**.

No, there is no violation of equivalence principle, since bosonic components of torsion still vanish. Whereas fermionic components give gravitino-matter coupling. See this answer for gravitino contribution https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/134689/85745

Comment: Can it be seen somehow as a 'yes' answer, if we assume a first order approach to supergravity, reformulated as an Einstein-Cartan theory of gravity coupled to spin-$\frac{3}{2}$ massless Rarita-Schwinger fields?

Comment: supergravity automatically assumes presence of fermions (gravitino in pure supergravity), that's the point of supersymmetry. And because of fermions, first-order formulation must be used.

Comment: well, you can technically add fermions without using vielbeins, but you will have to use spin base group, spin metric, and that kind of stuff.

Comment: Let me double check: does the fact that in supergravity (with gravitino) the non-vanishing torsion (see this [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/233329) ) *implies* a violation of the Equivalence Principle? See another [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/6573) saying that Einstein-Cartan theory does not obey the Equivalence Principle as "spin" components could result in a different measure in a gravitational field. Notice that [recent experiments](https://phys.org/news/2014-07-equivalence-principle-effects-spin-gravity-coupling.html) follow this test approach indeed

Comment: No, there is no violation of equivalence principle, since bosonic components of torsion still vanish. Whereas fermionic components give gravitino-matter coupling. See this answer for gravitino contribution https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/134689/85745

Comment: Thanks - That's what I was actually asking (about "theoretical models predicting that spin and gravity should couple"): I guess it would be great to include it in the answer ;)